# Assign material to face hotkey doesnt work

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, shaders, shortcut

How to make make a hotkey for "Assign" button? (Edit mesh mode)It is under all material slots in properties\material properties\Assign. What a button does - it applies selected material slot to selected polygons. What i want to do - is pressing lets say "K" on keyboard in 3D viewport to apply selected material slot to multiple selected faces. (RIGHT CLICK\ASSIGN SHORTCUT - doesnt work for this one)

Comment: Even if i Right click\Assign shortcut - the hotkey appears in "Object mode" section of shortcuts. Which is strange, because "Assign" button only appear in "Mesh" mode. Tho, operator itself is called "object.material_slot_assign" and i cant find equivalent for mesh mode.

Comment: I have no idea why this is not possible. A workaround would be to add it to the quick favourites instead. A quick question for understanding: why do you need this? If I have multiple materials on a mesh, then usually each face is either assigned to the default material slot or some other. So when I select faces which have other materials, the slot to which they are assigned in that moment gets selected. In this case I have to move my mouse to the material slots and choose the one I want to assign - but then I'm already where the button is...?

Comment: Yeah, you get the point. Material slot gets selected automatically after last selected polygon (active polygon its called and highlighted white). So i can select polygon area where i want to replace material, and select  polygon with desired material - boom, they all are of desired material now. Favourites workaround works, but its extra button click, which is very annoying since i use that hundreds of times every day.

Comment: I'm not sure about your workflow... hundreds of times sounds annoying, I assume there must be another way of doing it more efficiently. But since I don't know what you are actually doing I cannot tell why there would not be a better way of doing it. It seems as if you have to manually select a lot of faces all the time, so I wonder if this cannot be done differently.

Comment: cant really find a more logical workflow except editing it all manually. I work as archviz in architecture. I only do visuals. And my architects really love changing stuff here and there. Reimporting their dwg files for each fix sounds very frustrating. And also importing dwgs is a nightmare on its own. Since someones dwg files may include blocks which are 99999999999999 square kilometers wide and same for height. Importing that much corrupted dwgs is an art on its own. So i prefer to avoid reimporting their files if i can and manually fix minor changes.

Comment: so for me, the speed and accessibility of simple tools is very highly valuable since i cant really automate the process

Comment: This would be a too long discussion not suitable for this site. I usually have to import STL and OBJ files and often change materials on lots of parts, but almost never I have to set them manually on hundreds of faces we are probably doing things differently. The materials are the least annoying work when fixing those imported files.